# Cakephp 2.4.5, classic Auth seem block opengraph request

Tags: facebook, cakephp, authentication, block, facebook-opengraph

I was using classic Auth without any problem while I want to put some social button.

With Facebook or G+ button, I see no image on the share card create by the button... after some inspection, I realized CakePHP seems to block opengraph requests.

Open Graph Object Debugger says "error 200" and I suppose the cakephp Auth component blocked it.

But, in my first controlleur, every action are granted ($this->Auth->allow();) but nothing change....

How can I authorize Opengraph requests with the cakephp Auth component?

Comment: which version of cakephp?

Comment: I use the 2.4.5 version of CakePHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the problem was cause by the Gzip compression used by the server.
Disable this feature (with .htaccess) resolve the problem...